# How to fetch Data in Common Component from different Routs?

Tags: reactjs

I'm create the Common Component for show team info for Different Department. Department list is create dynamically e.g 
I have two URL "department/2/team" and department/3/team"

2 and 3 are the department id i fetch this with  match.params.id. when i Click on the first department link it show the info of there team. but i click the next department link URL change and params update but the list of team not updated.

I will fetch team info in the componentWillMount method. when i fetch team info in the componentWillUpdate / componentDidUpdate it will create the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to do this in componentWillReceiveProps because, once the component is loaded, changing route on the same page will not unmount and create new component, instead only prop are getting changed, make sure the old props and new props are not same before triggering the calls to avoid unwanted calls to the API

Comment: How i get the old props in componentWillReceiveProps?

Comment: It is not recommended to use `componentWillReceiveProps`, but combination of `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate`.  https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Comment: the current props on your component will be the old props that is going to change to the new props, the new props you will get as a parameter  (newProps) in that event